Reinforcing solid plank floor
Out apartment house is built 1939 and it seems that we have inherited original solid oak plank floor. It is made of approx. 2cm thick and quite long oak boards with grooves. Each board is made up of industrially glued smaller parquet pieces. These boards are laid directly upon the underlying beams. The beams, in turn, are placed on underfloor and solid concrete some 10 cm beneath the wood surface (covered with sand and construction dust). An older image from another room is attached as a reference, the smaller wooden supports seen in this image are local and not expected elsewhere.

Our problem is that at certain plank joints either the grooves have broken off or the distance to the support beams is too long. Either way, the flood is giving in at these locations. It is hard to show how it gives in, but when walked upon it sinks 2-3mm at least. Location in need of reinforcement are marked with tape.


We can't afford and don't have time to change all of the floor, also we kind of like it. Therefore we are looking for options to reinforce it, preferably without completely ruining the surface. This far we have come up with following options:

Drill holes and fill with supporting foam.
Drill holes and place supporting screws which press against the concrete beneath.
Carefully cut out the weak board sections with a saw and add wood support underneath, place the boards back and cover it up with a carpet.

We are looking for any advice or alternative ideas.

Where is this--country and city? How many apartment units in the building? As far as you can tell does the entire apartment have this type of floor?

The top layer of flooring is nowadays generally installed over a "subfloor" of sheet material (plywood or OSB) laid over the floor members below. Before about 1950, the subfloor was rough, wider planks of uniform thickness laid at 45 deg over the supporting joists and facenailed. The finished floor was installed over that. It seems you are missing the subfloor.  Ordinary floor planks installed directly to the floor joists cannot give a satisfactory result.

It could be this is the only room floored this way. Possibly the floor in this one room was lower than the rest of the apartment and this was done to raise the level to that of the rest of the apartment. Are the plank floors in other rooms doing better than this room or are all the floors showing this problem?

OP, you could revise you question to remove your description of the floor as "parquet". These are planks. Evidently the planks are made from glued shorter pieces which is done in parquet, but you have planks.

The apartment house, a dussin apartments, is in a town (northern Europe). When it comes to floor type, there are some exceptions such as bathroom (tile), kitchen (unclear) and bedroom (pine planks), but apart from that this type of floor is everywhere. Also in some other apartments. The problem is universal across the house, in other apartments as well, but is most evident at locations where people walk often.

So do you think these built up floors over concrete are everywhere in the apartment? I was imagining that the room you asked about was originally an exposed porch with a concrete floor that was later closed in. Such porches were common in the US in fully and semi-detached houses built in the 1940s. Nearly always these screened porches were later closed in and the floor raised with joists to be on the same level as other floors in the house. In every case I have seen from the 1950s to the present day sheet subflooring was emplaced on the joists and the finish floor placed on that subfloor.

The room is most definitely an indoor area from the start. Apartment is located on the top floor with balcony located elsewhere. After seeing renovation at some neighbor's places I firmly believe this type of floor is typical for most of the building. However I am not positive that all areas have underlying concrete. If fact some rooms seem to have wooden support structures based on old construction drawings.

Raised wooden floors over concrete is used in certain tpes of Japanese construction. There is a tract development in Dallas TX USA that I have been told has wooden floors raised 6" ( 15 cm) over a concrete slab.

Your solution of screws through the floor will only cause more damage.  Don't do that.
The injection of foam, could work, but it isn't the best solution.
The proper way to fix your problem is to carefully remove the floor boards and reinforce the supporting framing underneath.
Add blocking, ( wood attached at 90 degrees between 2 existing pieces.) This should be 2x4s or 2x6s or the largest size that will fit from the base to the top of the framing.
It is unknown what dimensions you are working with and you are probably outside the US, so the sizes of the wood framing you can use will have to be determined by you.
You may be able to add shims under some of the wood that is weak.
A better description of what the floor support structure is could get you even better answers. However the simple idea of adding extra members will help stiffen the floor.

Yes, adding sleepers in the "soft" spots will help.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there's an easy way to do do without some demolition.

We also have a suspicion that the planks may be nailed to the beams. (Hidden, at an angle in the grooves), but this is unconfirmed. That would make the demolition task slightly harder.

On a subjective scale, where would you expect the result of support member strategy to be? To remove the boards we will need to cut the grooves (no way to remove the boards otherwise) and I'm somewhat worried that the boards will not be stable/firm afterwards and/or that the long horizontal cut will look terrible.

I don't think any of your proposals will work. Foam would not firmly support the planks and if you used too much, it could lift the floor planks. Also if you ever had a water leak at present it can dry out, but with foam is could stay wet and rot. Lifting screws to the concrete? Never done and can't see how it would work. Reinforcing under each failing joint? Can't see how that would work.
Possibly you could work some clear epoxy glue into a joint that is separating, cover with plastic sheet, and then flatten the joint with a heavy weight on a flat board. You could try this on one or more joints and see if it works.
The only real solution would be to remove all the planks, install sheet subfloor, then put the planks back, or some other flooring. Depending on their condition after removal, you might decide against reinstalling the old planks.
One possible way remove discontinuities at end joints with the flooring in place would be insert something like a ring shank nail into the joint and use a heay hammer or other force to press the upper plank down to the level of the lower one. The nail would be cut off and driven below the finish level with a nail punch.

Some floor professionals (unclear how trustworthy), when asked about same issue proposed removing this floor section, adding some support wood and then re-sanding and re-polishing all flooring. But that is too big of a task, in similar way to your final suggestion. If any other creative ideas like epoxy come up, please share.

In one of the pictures it looks like a straight cut with a saw was used to open up the floor. Is that what you did?

It was not done by us, but yes, I believe it was simply sawed off. That location is somewhat atypical as a part of the floor was missing due to old built in wardrobe being in that location at some point. To cover the area after the wardrobe removal the floor was cut and filled with similar plank pieces.
